# Converting curl in bash to php

Tags: php, bash, curl

Well, here's my cURL script inside bash that works without any issues!

```
#!/bin/bash
fileid="1yvklOFopnep8twiqAQecmMUoAbQVzU0r"
filename="MyFile.mp4"
curl -c ./cookie -s -L "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=${fileid}" > /dev/null
curl -Lb ./cookie "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=`awk '/download/ {print $NF}' ./cookie`&id=${fileid}" -o ${filename}
```

However I'm trying to rewrite this into a simple PHP script, although it appears not to be working correctly; here's the code:

```
<?php

    define('FILENAME', 'MyFile.mp4');
    define('FILE_ID', '1yvklOFopnep8twiqAQecmMUoAbQVzU0r');

    $GlobalFileHandle = null;

    function get_confirm($id)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=".$id);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        preg_match_all("/confirm=([0-9A-Za-z]+)&/", $result, $output_array);
        return $output_array[1][0];
    }

    function get_file($id, $confirm)
    {
        global $GlobalFileHandle;
        $GlobalFileHandle = fopen(FILENAME, 'w+');
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm='.$confirm.'&id='.$id);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $GlobalFileHandle);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'curlWriteFile');
        curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($GlobalFileHandle);
    }

    function curlWriteFile($cp, $data)
    {
        global $GlobalFileHandle;
        return fwrite($GlobalFileHandle, $data);
    }

    $confirm_code = get_confirm(FILE_ID);

    echo "We got our confirm code! ".$confirm_code;

    get_file(FILE_ID, $confirm_code);
```

However it appears the file is not being downloaded & the MyFile.mp4 remains empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to mix several options in an invalid way here.

Since you set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` the data is *returned* by `curl_exec()`.

So

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
fwrite($GlobalFileHandle, $data);
```

should do the trick. If you want to use the callbacks, do not set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` at all.

Another option is, to set `CURLOPT_FILE` to write the data directly to a file handle (don't set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` either then):

```
curl_setopt(CURL_FILE, $GlobalFileHandle);
```

Furthermore, you need to set the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` to your cookiejar to have the cookies *read* correctly. The `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` option only sets the file where to *store* cookies to. You need both, so *add*:

```
curl_setopt(CURL_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
```

For more details, refer to the [curl_setopt PHP manpage](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.curl-setopt.php)

Comment: It appears I'm now getting content but it's a HTML Page of "Google Drive - Virus scan warning" as to which I don't get when using the bash script

Comment: @Curtis Probably a cookie problem, see the edit

Comment: You hit the nail on the head! it was the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a `curl_exec` is missing in function `get_file`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to attach!